# How to implement a wx.TextCtrl in a wx.GridBagSizer?

Tags: python, wxpython

this is my code: http://pastebin.com/WwZri3e3

id like to know how i could implement a text box on the right side of each label
First name
surname
and username.

the wxpython documentation is very poor and ive tried everything i could in order to get a better learning experience with wxpython, and at the moment im just swinging through the air.

i find that studying others code helps alot more than reading the documentation.

can anyone provide some insight? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i typically make a horizontal boxsizer

```
def addWithLabel(parent,label,wxCtrl):
       sz_h1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
       txt = wx.StaticText(parent,-1,label)
       sz_h1.Add(txt)
       sz_h1.Add(wxCtrl)
       return sz_h1

my_vertical_sizer.Add(addWithLabel(my_parent,"Some Label:",wx.TextCtrl(my_parent,-1)))
```

alternatively you could add your gridbagsizer to your boxsizer instead of the other way around ...

Answer (score 0):

I generally just use the a GridBagSizer alone and some positioning variables to keep things flexible.

The scratchpad version looks like this:

```
self.gbs = wx.GridBagSizer(hgap=5, vgap=5)
lbl_name_first = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label = "First Name :" )
txt_name_first = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,size=(200,-1))
self.gbs.Add(lbl_name_first, pos=(1, 1))
self.gbs.Add(txt_name_first, pos=(1, 2))
```

If you define a few "constants" for horizontal positioning and a row count for vertical positioning, things start to look like the code below. Naming the columns and spans really comes in handy when need to create a little extra space somewhere.

```
# all caps mark 'constants'
COL_LEFT_LABEL = 2
COL_LEFT_FIELD = 3
SPAN_FULL_WIDTH = 4
nRowPosition = 1

lbl_name_first = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label = "First Name :" )
txt_name_first = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,size=(200,-1))
self.gbs.Add(lbl_name_first, pos=(nRowPosition, COL_LEFT_LABEL))
self.gbs.Add(txt_name_first, pos=(nRowPosition, COL_LEFT_FIELD), flag=wx.EXPAND, span=(1, SPAN_FULL_WIDTH))
nRowPosition += 1
```

You can (and should) refine it further, but this should get you started.